# How to do case insensitive string comparison in a Blazor/Razor page with embedded C#?

Tags: c#, string, razor, blazor, ignore-case

There are many related questions (and answers) like this (case insensitive string comparison), but none are for Razor C# pages.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and Blazor (Razor pages and C#).  Browser is Chrome or Edge (oddly, it works fine in Internet Exploder...)

In my razor page, I'm trying to set the "selected" option on an HTML select option IF the passed URL parameter matches an item in my string array.  But the **variable.Equals(param,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)** or **String.Equals(param,variable,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnnoreCase)** fails unless the case of the parameter matches exactly.

I'm getting my string array using Entity Framework and a SQL Server database.  But to illustrate the problem, I've condensed it down to 1 Razor page (no EF and no database):

```
@page "/EqualsTest/{incomingParam}"
<h3>EqualsTest</h3>

<p>incomingParam = @incomingParam</p>

<!--display list on page to show lengths-->
@foreach (var p in myParams)
{
    <p>'@p' = @p.Length</p>
}

<!--select list with passed param selected if it matches-->
<select @bind="@incomingParam">
    @foreach (var p in myParams)
    {
        @if (incomingParam.Equals(p, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            <option selected value="@p">@p</option>
        }
        else
        {
            <option value="@p">@p</option>
        }
    }
</select>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string incomingParam { get; set; }

    IEnumerable<string> myParams = new List<string>(){
        "Hello",
        "Whazzzup",
        "Goodbye"
    };
}
```

I tried using the String class rather than string variables but it still behaves the same.

I tried using an interim string variable to see if that made a difference, still no werky.

If the browser URL does not match exactly, the select option will not be selected.  For example, this works:

```
 http://localhost:35333/EqualsTest/Hello
```

And this does not:

```
 http://localhost:35333/EqualsTest/hello
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Side note: if that would be Razor pages `@if` inside code code block started by `@foreach` is very suspicious...

Comment: You're working in Blazor, please update the title and the tags

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I loop thru the array in the @code section the string compare works fine.

I can use this hack in the @code section to work around the problem:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    foreach (var p in myParams)
    {
        if (incomingParam.Equals(p,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            incomingParam = p;
        }
    }
}
```

And now the string comparison in the Razor C# code works correctly.

But I would like to know why it does not work in the Razor page without this silly business.

**UPDATE:** Better - no compiler warnings:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    base.OnInitialized();

    foreach (var p in myParams)
    {
        if (String.Equals(p, incomingParam, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            incomingParam = p;
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**:  And even better - change the parameter get/set properties:

```
@code {
    IEnumerable<string> myParams = new List<string>()
    {
        "Hello",
        "Whazzzup",
        "Goodbye"
    };

    private string _incomingParam;

    [Parameter]
    public string incomingParam
    {
        get => _incomingParam;
        set
        {
            _incomingParam = value; // set the default

            foreach (var p in myParams)
            {
                if (String.Equals(p, value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    _incomingParam = p;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly due to that `@bind` in `<select @bind="@incomingParam">`
try binding to a new variable, or not bind at all for a test...

However, personally, I'd suggest that you keep all in lower case and just `.ToLower()` whatever param you receive

**UPDATE**
I've looked arround a bit and it seems that @bind supports @bind:converter
so you can use [`LowerCaseStringConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.lowercasestringconverter?view=netframework-4.8)

```cs
 <select @bind="@incomingParam" @bind-converter="LowerCaseStringConverter">
    @foreach (var p in myParams)
    {
        @if (incomingParam.Equals(p, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            <option selected value="@p">@p</option>
        }
        else
        {
            <option value="@p">@p</option>
        }
    }
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I tried binding to another string variable, as I mentioned in the post, but the result was the same.  And I agree, I tried ToLower() on the param but it still did not work.  The compare in the page still fails.

Comment: Per your suggestion I removed the bind from the select and the option gets selected correctly.  But ... I don't know what the user selected, which is what I need.  So it's definitely something to do with the bind.  Seems more and more like a Razor bug.

Comment: It's not a bug, It's normal (bind is a two way binding, you don't need the code to set the selected at all, it'll change it)...I'm suggesting you just `ToLower` the param at the very beginning and deal with the lower case version all along,

Comment: As I mentioned, I tried that, but the lower case param is being compared to what is in the array, to decide whether to set the "selected" attribute.  But the string compare in the page fails when comparing the param value (lower or not), to what is in the array.  I could ToLower() all the array elements but then the user would see all lower case values, rather than what is in the database.

Comment: I like the idea, but did you test your code?  I tried and I get syntax errors and it will not build.  I was not able to find any reference to bind-converter to see what an example looks like.

Comment: @ByteSlinger, I actually haven't tested that, maybe try creating a converter instance as a property in your `@code` section and `bind-converter` to that?
I'm planning on writing an extensive description w\ test cases for that, but I'm not that free right now